# WinRT XAML GridView not limited by RowHeight

Tags: c#, xaml, gridview, windows-runtime

My page layout goes like this:

I have my MainGrid defined like this:

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="100" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="75" />
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

I have a header, footer, and the main content.

I have a GridView in the main content, the middle row.  The GridView itself does not have a height declaration.  When I view the page, the GridView spills it's content beyond the viewable area.

My understand is that it should be limited by the above row definitions.  Am I missing something here?

Comment: Is the `GridView` inside of that Grid? Is `Grid.Row="1"` and `Grid.RowSpan="1"` or unset? Is `Margin="0"`?

Comment: The `Grid.Row="1"` would be only thing required, the rest is default anyway. Maybe the OP can share more of an example that includes the child GridView, should be an easy fix.

Comment: The GridView is inside a stackpanel that has Grid.Row="1" set.

Comment: StackPanels are reknowned for not filling the given space. I would try your best to remove it from the stack panel, or try setting the stackpanel's `VerticalAlignment` and `VerticalContentAlignment` to `Stretch`.

Comment: I just got rid of the stack panel, and replaced it with another grid with two rows.  Works as I wanted now. Thanks!